# Oracle SQL select with grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables - A and B. A relationship to B is 1:M.

I would like to do a fancy grouping select so I get results like this - http://prntscr.com/3dvpm9

Which function I should investigate to get such result?

Comment: Do you want to have empty values under the first value of each group?

Comment: Lesya, yes. I want A entity to be displayed only once and then its related entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
decode
(row_number() over(partition by id order by column1, column2),1, id, null)
ids , column1, column2
from table1
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/41766/4)

Same logic applies fortwo related tables:

```
select 
decode
(row_number() 
over(partition by table2.id order by table2.column1, table2.column2),
1, table1.id, null)
ids , table2.column1, table2.column2
from table1 left join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59d6f/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` like this :

```
SELECT
    A.prop
    ,B.prop
FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN B
        ON A.related_field = B.related_field
```